# Getting GLFW together with glad to work on windows

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glfw, glad

i wanted to start a small project using OpenGL. I have done similar things in Java before and wanted to transfer some code to C++.

I started with installing `glfw` using `msys2`:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw
```

Beside that, I had a `glad.c` and `glad.h` generated online [here](https://glad.dav1d.de/) which I added to my project files

Furthermore, to verify my installation I downloaded a very small sample code:

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

This did not compile so I manually changed the imports to

```cpp
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include "glad.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

I compile using Cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(Engine3D)

find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


add_executable(Engine3D glad.h glad.c main.cpp)


target_link_libraries(Engine3D glfw)
target_link_libraries(Engine3D OpenGL::GL)
```

---

## The Problem

So the code did compile using the code above, yet it crashes immediately. I tracked the issue down to this line:

```cpp
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

After commenting out that line, It does not hang or crash and simply displays a black background.

I was wondering for which reason the sample code I downloaded is not working the way it should.

I am very happy for any help or explanation.

Comment: adding glad is not enough, you need to initialize it with `gladLoadGLLoader()`

Comment: It requres some GLADLoadproc: `int gladLoadGLLoader(GLADloadproc load)` Do you know how this would be implemented?

I tried adding

`
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize OpenGL context" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
`

Which is eventually terminating the program

Comment: Lovely. it works! Thanks. Feel free to answer the question and I will quickly accept it asap

Comment: Yes it answers my question. I did not know I had to initialise it too.